Android Studio doesn't know where "hg" is
My android studio doesn't know where "hg" is
I already installed Mercurial
OS: Windows 11
If I replace as "hg.bat", it works. But I can't replace them all
How to fix?
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hg": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.Instrumented.exec(Instrumented.java:250)
    at Config.execReadStandardOutOrThrow(ConfigPlugin.kt:204)
    at Config.execReadStandardOutOrThrow$default(ConfigPlugin.kt:203)
    at Config.getVcsHash(ConfigPlugin.kt:184)
    at Config$getVcsHash.call(Unknown Source)
    at build_4y7vgpadg1wghwfvlmkpx6hcz$_run_closure1$_closure16.doCall$original(D:\RESEARCH\mozilla-source\mozilla-unified\mobile\android\fenix\app\build.gradle:125)
    at build_4y7vgpadg1wghwfvlmkpx6hcz$_run_closure1$_closure16.doCall(D:\RESEARCH\mozilla-source\mozilla-unified\mobile\android\fenix\app\build.gradle)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:73)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:149)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:167)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.create(AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.create(AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.NamedDomainObjectContainerConfigureDelegate._configure(NamedDomainObjectContainerConfigureDelegate.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:72)
    at build_4y7vgpadg1wghwfvlmkpx6hcz$_run_closure1$_closure17.doCall$original(D:\RESEARCH\mozilla-source\mozilla-unified\mobile\android\fenix\app\build.gradle:144)




bat files can not be executed like exe files. Bat files are interpreted like Python files therefore you need cmd.exe to execute a bat file. If you execute a bat file by Windows this is done automatically. If you want to start a bat file in your own program you have to manually use cmd.exe /c my.bat to run it.BTW why do you try to use an hg.bat file instead of hg.exe?

TortoiseHg contains an hg.exe.

Thanks. I have to download Mercurial installing-files from their official site. Reinstall and it works
